# get_text() has UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="dialog">
<div class="title title-with-sort-row">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <div class="dialog-search-sort-bar">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content"><div style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 30px;">
    <span class="description2">
        With “Antonia Polygon – Standard”, you have a figure that is unique in the Poser community. 
        She is made available under a Creative Commons License that gives endless opportunities for further development. 
        This figure was developed by a group of talented members of the Poser community in a thirty-month effort. 
        The result is a figure that has very good bending and morphing behavior.
        <br />
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to find this div out of several divs of `class="dialog"`, then pull out the text in `span class="description2"`.

When I use the code:

```
description = soup.find(text = re.compile('Description'))
if description != None:
    someEl = description.parent
    parent1 = someEl.parent
    parent2 = parent1.parent
    description = parent2.find('span', {'class' : 'description2'})
    print 'Description: ' + str(description)
```

I get:

```
<span class="description2">
    With Â“Antonia Polygon Â– StandardÂ”, you have a figure that is unique in the Poser community. 
    She is made available under a Creative Commons License that gives endless opportunities for further development. 
    This figure was developed by a group of talented members of the Poser community in a thirty-month effort. 
    The result is a figure that has very good bending and morphing behavior.
    <br/>
</span>
```

If I try to get just the text, without the HTML & non-ASCII chars, using

```
description = description.get_text()
```

I get a **`(UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codex can't encode character u'\x93'`**

How do I convert this block of HTML to straight ascii?

Comment: The character `“` is not an ASCII character. Is your goal to identify the most similar character that is ASCII (that's hard), or is your goal to simply remove all non-ASCII characters? Or is what you really want to output proper Unicode, e.g. UTF-8, rather than ASCII?

Comment: Just to remove all non-ascii chars

Comment: Obligatory: http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

foo = u'With Â“Antonia Polygon Â– StandardÂ”, you have a figure that is unique in the Poser community.She is made available under a Creative Commons License that gives endless opportunities for further development. This figure was developed by a group of talented members of the Poser community in a thirty-month effort. The result is a figure that has very good bending and morphing behavior.'

print foo.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Three things to notice.

First is the `'ignore'` parameter to the encode method. It instructs the method to drop characters that aren't in range of the selected encoding (in this case, ascii to be safe).

Second is that we're explicitly setting foo to be unicode by prepending the string with a `u`.

Third is the explicit file encoding directive: `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`.

Also, if you don't read Daenyth's very good points in comments attached to this answer then you are a silly clod. `xmlcharrefreplace` can be used for great justice in the stead of `ignore` above if the output is to be used in HTML/XML.

Comment: Using `xmlcharrefreplace` for the 2nd parameter would be a lot better in this case since he's dealing with html.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm just being lazy since OP said in a comment he just wants to remove all the misbehaving characters. :)

Comment: Still, it's worth mentioning since other people may come across this if they have a similar problem.